# iPhone top of gadgets cut off first time it is drawn

Tags: ios, ipad

I'm trying to put a ad on top of my iPad app.  I have the y corder net as zero.  It seems like the first time the add is drawn it is drawn with the y cordernt starting at the very top.  So the bar with the battery power and internet strength gets drawn onto.  If you clcim on the add, and then return to the app the add is dawn right under the battery stregth bar with the y cordet still zero.

If i set the y to 60, it will look good at first, but then when you click on the add bar and then return to the add, the add is drawn 60 pixels below the battery bar instead of right under neath it.

It seems like sometimes the y starts at the very top of the screen, then it starts right below the battery stretch bar.

There must be a way to fix this,......

code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.


    // AddCode
    adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait];
    adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
    [self.view addSubview:adView];
    adView.delegate=self;
    bannerIsVisible=NO;

}
 // i removes all the code to make sure nothing was messing it up
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect, if you play with it some you will find the issue is with the app launching in orientations other than portrait (either landscape or upside down).

I had a very similar problem and was able to get it working by fiddling with the `wantsFullScreenLayout` property on my UIViewController subclasses.  The documentation of this property seems to imply that the correct value is NO, but try setting it to YES on your main view controller.

Comment: Hi,Thank you for taking your time to reply to my quastion, I still cannot get it to work, could it have something to due with this being a dual app?