# view is hidden behind status bar when push segue with hidden nav bar or modal segue

Tags: ios, segue, statusbar, viewcontroller

I am trying to segue to a view that does not show a nav bar. If I do a push segue to the view and hide the nav bar then part of the view is hidden behind the status bar, it should be displayed 20 points below the status status bar so it is not obscured, same thing happens if I do a modal segue. It only displays correctly if I do a push segue but dont hide the nav bar.

Im not sure why this is happening, I can work around it by shifting the view down 20 points but that seems like a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I was directed to another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403251/iphone-top-of-gadgets-cut-off-first-time-it-is-drawn) which suggested playing around with the wantsFullScreenLayout property of the view controller so I added this to the viewWillAppear:

self.wantsFullScreenLayout = NO;

that seemed to fix the issue, not sure why I needed it as I thought the default was for this value to be NO, but its working now